# Python request.post to php server

Tags: php, python, json

Different variants of this question litter google, but I am not finding a solution specific to my needs.  I am trying to send a JSON string from a client running python to a web server that is using PHP.  The JSON string contains the results from a select query.

I have found lots of examples and tutorials on how to generate the JSON in python and how to publish data from the server database to a user via the server's page.

What I am not finding is how to actually transfer the JSON from the Python script to the PHP script.  I am using the Arduino YUN with Linino, and have tried a request.post() but get a "module not found" error.

A plain english explanation of how the data hand off should take place between the two devices would help greatly!  Any suggestions on a good resource that actually shows an example of what I have described would be great too.

Python (Post):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
import json

url = 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/reciever.php'
payload = {"device":"gabriel","data_type":"data","zone":1,"sample":4,"count":0,"time_stamp":"00:00"}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

PHP (Receiver):

```
<?php

print_r(json_decode($_POST['payload']));

?>
```

Maybe there is a totally different way that is better for posting a select query from a client to a server?  Client will have dynamic IP's and the server will be web based.

Comment: Try `data=json.dumps({"payload": payload})`.

Comment: Or `requests.post(url, data={'payload':json.dumps(payload)},...`

Comment: The `payload` won't turn up in a form variable called `payload` on the PHP side. Though if you change the python to `response = requests.post(url, data=dict(payload=json.dumps(payload)), headers=headers)` I think it should.

Comment: In the PHP I'd do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what comes out.

Comment: Looks like it's not able to find your PHP site. I think that means it's failing on the DNS lookup? Try `curl http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/reciever.php ` directly from the command line to see what you get. EDIT the post has changed - I guess this isn't an issue anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library `requests` isn't installed in Python by default. You need to get it first via `pip` or another package manager:

```
pip install requests
```

After that, you can use it.

There is also library, that is built in: `urllib2`. Example:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/reciever.php'
payload = {"device":"gabriel","data_type":"data","zone":1,"sample":4,"count":0,"time_stamp":"00:00"}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}    
data = urllib.urlencode(payload)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Comment: After loading the request module as suggested and adding "import json" No errors were detected.